# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in in my php file

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to write a code in php code  for update a table but i am getting a waring here   why i am getting  this warning here

Here is my code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","clothing");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['change'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql="SELECT *from userdetails WHERE userId='$userid'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if ($count > 0){
        echo $row["Password"];
        echo  $_POST["currentPassword"];
        if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["Password"]) {
            echo "fine";
        if( $_POST["confirmPassword"]== $_POST["newPassword"]){
            mysqli_query("UPDATE userdetails SET Password='anil' WHERE ID=30");
            echo "good";
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get my desired output

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the warning text not clear enough? Look at the line before `echo "good";`: you have to pass *two* parameters to `mysqli_query`, you are only passing *one*. (Also, storing user passwords as plaintext is awfully wrong.)

Comment: DCoder   what shoud i write there

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't include $con on your query.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE userdetails SET Password='anil' WHERE ID=30");
```

without adding $con, your query will fail.

Comment: @crazymoin: I'll bet the error is because the OP mixed up column names: the earlier query used `userId`, this one uses `ID` (not to mention the user IDs and passwords are hardcoded in this query, not taken from user input...).

Comment: i am getting  Error : ()

Comment: @Terminus Software I fixed what you needed. Have a look at my answer

Comment: @Terminus Software I don't think  there is any error in my answer. Are you getting any error or you are getting no results

Comment: @TerminusSoftware try this: if (mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE userdetails SET Password='anil' WHERE ID=30")) { echo "successfully query"; } else {     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con); } let us know what problem showing

Comment: @DCoder OP can use two different id, "ID" for index and unique of this table, "userId" for creating relation with user table!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the two paremeters to the mysqli_query - $con . Use the code below

```
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","clothing");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

        if(isset($_POST['change']))
        {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
            $sql="SELECT *from userdetails WHERE userId='$userid'";

        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                $count=mysqli_num_rows($con,$query);
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($con,$query);
                if ($count > 0){
                echo $row["Password"];
                echo  $_POST["currentPassword"];
                if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["Password"]) {
                echo "fine";
                if( $_POST["confirmPassword"]== $_POST["newPassword"])
        {

        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE userdetails SET Password='anil' WHERE ID=30");
        echo "good";
         }

       }

     }
     }
```

Hope this helps you